dispose MultiProviders when i logout
How can I clear the current state of my providers manually in my Flutter app? The use case I have is when a user signs out of my app then signs up as a new/different user the previous users state is still stored in the providers, it is cleared automatically when the app is restarted however.
there are my providers:
`
class GlobalProviderApp {
  static providers() => [
        /// global modules
        Provider.value(value: RepositoryImp),

        /// pos modules
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SyncDataController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => LoginController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuditLogController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ForgetPasswordController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SignupController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TargetController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ClassificationController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CurrencyController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CustomerController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => DepartmentController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => EmployeeController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => OrderBillController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ItemController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PriceController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PayMethodsController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WarehouseController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SupplierController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UnitsController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BackupController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MainModule()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MainController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BranchController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PermissionController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SettingsController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PosController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AccountController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AccountController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AccountTypeController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BranchSupplierController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ContactSupplierController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PriceTypeController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TypeCustomerController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TypeSupplierController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ShelveController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CashierController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ShelveController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PaymentVoucherController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ReceiptVoucherController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => DailyEntryController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SaleReturnBillController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PurchaseReturnBillController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PurchaseBillController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => QuotationBillController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TaxController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CompanyController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ASCollectiveController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ASDetailsController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => FinalSalesController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => JournalEntryController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => VoucherController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CustomerReportController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SupplierReportController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ProductReportController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BillCollectiveController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TrialBalanceController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BillCustomerDetailsController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WarehouseTypeController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ChannelController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ChannelItemController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WarehouseDisposalController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AccountFreePageController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WarehouseSupplyController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CustomerOrderController()),
      ]..addAll(providerGateway());

  static providerGateway() => [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ServiceMainController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => OrderReportController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PaymentReportController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => RemittanceReportController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => OrderController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ConfirmPurchaseController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SendPurchaseController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PaymentController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => RemittanceController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ReceiveRemittanceController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SendRemittanceController()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SettingGatewayController()),
      ];
}


and i use theme here:
runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: GlobalProviderApp.providers(),
    child: MyApp(),
  ));```


can you help me please,,how can i dispose the all provideres when i logout?


You should provide each one in their corresponding tree location, if you use instantiate all of them at root that kind of problems will happen, state should be local to their respective location no globally.
